# How redirect to previous request after login in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller to download files only to register users, for example:

> www.myapp.com/download/123.jpg

But if a register user enter in this link but in this moment isn't logged, the system send him to log in page.

I need the user after of login, come back to the first url .../download/123.jpg

How is it possible in Symfony2?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this works out of the box when you follow the book/cookbook. Please provide some code (controller, view, security.yml) and/or an explanation what currently happens to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks, I search in the cookbock but I don't found how to do this.

Comment: post your security.yml file

Answer (score 1):

This is configured in the form_login section of your security firewall:

```
# login success redirecting options (read further below)
always_use_default_target_path: false
default_target_path:            /
target_path_parameter:          _target_path
use_referer:                    false
```

If you have changed `always_use_default_target_path` to true, then the user would always be redirected to "/".  Another possibility is that you're not displaying the `_target_path` hidden element in your login form.  Since use_referer is false by default, if this hidden field is missing the redirect would fall back to the default target path.

This is all set up in security.yml and you can read more about configuration here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html